# Calling a function in Javascript Syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This might be a simple question but for some reason I can't find the solution. 
So I am new to Javascript and I had a lot of this code put on me to work on. So I am trying to call a function in a different HTML file and use it in a different HTML file. It just keeps printing out the statement.

So I included the file in the HTML using this

```
<xi:include href="model_pdb.html"/>
```

This is labeled in the  to call my Jquery Libraries and functions

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="viewer.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="render.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="blowup.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="RotateImages.js" ></script>
```

And I am calling the function in the  tag of this function

```
<body onload="readSingleFile('1igt.pdb','chothia', 'L', 'H' );">
    <div>
        <h1>The Antibody</h1>
        <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="${type.upper()}"/>

        ${pdb()}
```

In my model_pdb.html file the function is defined as here

```
<py:def function="pdb">
```

I figured it would of been as simple as that, but alas I am wrong. Any thoughts on what to do here?

Comment: XInclude isn't a technology that is widely supported by HTML web browsers - they're meant to be used in XML documents. Why don't you put your JavaScript inside of its own file, then reference the file with a `<script>` tag instead?

Comment: So I added a <script "text/html" src = "model_pdb.html"> in the head tag but still the same result

Comment: You can only reference `.js` files in `<script>` tags. I'm suggesting you make a new `.js` file with the JavaScript from that `.html` file.